# jQuery animate complete parameter, only works as anonymous function not as function pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I remove a dom element with following jQuery animation:

```
        var $id = $(this._id); // id of a dom element
        $id.animate({
            width:          "10vw",
            fontSize:       "0.33vw",
        }, 300, "swing", function() {
            $id.remove();
        });
```

This works fine. But I wanted to have it shorter and tried:

```
        var $id = $(this._id); // id of a dom element
        $id.animate({
            width:          "10vw",
            fontSize:       "0.33vw",
        }, 300, "swing", $id.remove);
```

This doesn't. Why not? I thought, that is the same ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$id.remove` as a *function pointer* (I call them function references) will lose its context, that is, the `this` value, meaning that `remove()` won't know what collection to work on.

Try passing `$.proxy($.fn.remove, $id)`. This will call jQuery's `remove()` method, using the context of `$id`. `$.proxy()` is a cross-browser implementation of `Function.prototype.bind()`.

It is often common to see the call wrapped in an anonymous function too to prevent the problem you ran into.

Comment: Anonymous function: You mean as I did in my example above? Your solution works fine. But there is no really short version for that?

Comment: @Michael That *is* the short version :P. If it looks too complicated, simply place an anonymous function there, of which its body is `$id.remove()`.